# Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver on Trigger.io Android app

Tags: android, push-notification, trigger.io, parse-platform

I've an Android app built with trigger.io, using Parse push notifications.
App is deployed to google play and push notifications have been working fine. Recently re-built and deployed to google play a new version of the app, with Forge platform version 1.4.29.

Since then I have been receiving the following crash reports through Google Play:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:125)
at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:119)
at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.<init>(ParseCommandCache.java:132)
at com.parse.Parse.getCommandCache(Parse.java:450)
at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1022)
at com.parse.ParseInstallation.saveEventually(ParseInstallation.java:170)
at com.parse.ParsePushRouter.saveEventually(ParsePushRouter.java:92)
at com.parse.ParsePushRouter.ensureStateIsLoaded(ParsePushRouter.java:208)
at com.parse.ParsePushRouter.hasRoutes(ParsePushRouter.java:122)
at com.parse.PushService.startServiceIfRequired(PushService.java:129)
at com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParseBroadcastReceiver.java:19)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
... 10 more
```

I have tested the app thoroughly on the following Android handsets and not been able to replicate the bug myself.

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus
- Samsung Galaxy S2
- Samsung Galaxy S

Can someone suggest what is going wrong here and how I can fix it with Trigger.io?

Comment: Are you using the latest SDK. I believe this was a Parse bug which was fixed in a recent update.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.11, listed as the latest version on the changelog here https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: An official answer from Trigger.IO would be useful here.

Comment: Could you send your app config and example code to support@trigger.io?

Comment: Sure, just sent a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Forge v1.4.37, which included an update to the Parse Android SDK v1.2.3.

- [Trigger.io release ntes](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html)
- [Bug report on Parse Q&A](https://parse.com/questions/androidcontentreceivercallnotallowedexception-when-registering-for-push-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had this problem and nothing to do with Parse version. Issue was the initializing of Parse was done on Activity instead of Application. The Broadcast Receiver can start before the Activity and writing a custom Application class and initializing Parse in onCreate of that helps.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Initialize Parse here
    }
}



<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
...>
.
.
.
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is resolved in Forge v1.4.32:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-32

Comment: After updating to v1.4.32, some of our users are still experiencing the crash with a slightly different stack trace. It starts with `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`. Even though it seems to affect less users, the number of crashes is still alarmingly high. Here is the relevant report in the Parse forums: https://parse.com/questions/androidcontentreceivercallnotallowedexception-when-registering-for-push-notifications

Comment: I'm also now receiving these new stack traces `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`