# Unfortunately, <AppName> has stopped using Cordova and Parse.com

Tags: cordova, parse-platform

Using Parse.com SDK and Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6, after not using the app for a while, when I turn the phone on, I receive an alert box of "Unfortunately,  has stopped".

I have found similar questions on StackOverflow, but none have solutions.  For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520438/app-stopped-when-i-click-on-notification-sent-using-parse-com

Has anyone figured out how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Can you give more info? The example you gave has to do with push notifications, is a push causing it to crash?

Comment: Hmmm, that link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs after I power down and restart the phone or after a period of inactivity when the phone is sleeping.

I believe I have resolved the issue based on comments provided in this thread: [Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver on Trigger.io Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811733/unable-to-start-receiver-com-parse-parsebroadcastreceiver-on-trigger-io-android)

Basically, I created a MyApplication.java file with the following:

```
package com.yourpackage.app;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Initialize Parse here
        Parse.initialize(this, "your details here", "your details here");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, CLA.class);
    }
}
```

I remove the Parse initialization code from the Activity file (which is where the Parse.com docs tell you to place this code!).

Then, make sure to make the following update to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication" ....
```

Hope this helps others,
Adam